# Generated dynamic query appending parameters in WHERE clause with syntax error based on condition SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a query in SQL Server, used `CTE`. The query is being generated dynamically each time the procedure get fired with multiple parameters in `WHERE clause` to be attached based on parameters having values. The problem is as there are multiple values to append based on condition. Therefore user may not pass any value, then there is no `WHERE clause`. But if user pass all parameters are any parameter then how should I append it using `and`. Because of this generated query having syntax error. How should I correct this?

```
declare @vflag varchar(50)=null, @udisecode varchar(20)='1141701604',  @district int=null,  @zone int=0, @block int=null,  
  @classid int=null, @className varchar(10)=null, @report varchar(20)=null, @gender varchar(6)=null,
  @religion int=null, @category int=null, @subjectid int=null, @subject varchar(30)=null,  
  @querystr varchar(MAX)=null
set @querystr='
    ;with cte1 as(
       select udise_no,student_regno,fullname,dob,domicile_yesno,admission_date,gender,class_id from tbl_personal
    ),cte2 as(
       select udise_no,student_regno,religion_id,student_category,student_caste from tbl_reservation
    ),cte3 as(
       select categoryname,ID from tbl_category
    ),cte4 as(
       select id,religion from tbl_religion
    ),cte5 as(
       select udisecode,school_name,district_id,block_id from school_master
    ),cte6 as(
       select district_id,district_name from district_master
    ),cte7 as(
       select block_id,block_name,district_id from block_master
    )

    select a.udise_no, a.fullname as studentname,a.gender,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,a.dob,106),'' '',''-'') as dob,
    ISNULL(d.categoryname,'''') as category,
    ISNULL(c.religion,'''') as religion,
    a.domicile_yesno as domicile,a.class_id as class,
    a.student_regno,
    schoolmaster.school_name,
    districtmaster.district_name as district,
    blockmaster.block_name
    from cte1 a

    left join cte2 b
    ON b.udise_no=a.udise_no and b.student_regno=a.student_regno

    left join cte4 c
    on c.ID=b.religion_id

    left join cte3 d
    on d.ID=b.student_category

    left join cte5 schoolmaster
    on a.udise_no=schoolmaster.udisecode

    left join cte6 districtmaster
    on districtmaster.district_id=schoolmaster.district_id

    left join cte7 blockmaster
    on blockmaster.district_id=districtmaster.district_id and 
       blockmaster.district_id=schoolmaster.district_id and
       blockmaster.block_id=schoolmaster.block_id' 


if(@district is not null OR @block is not null OR @udisecode is not null OR 
   @className is not null OR @category is not null OR @religion is not null OR
   @gender is not null)
  set @querystr += ' Where '
if(@district is not null)
  set @querystr += ' convert(varchar,schoolmaster.district_id) LIKE '''+ISNULL(convert(varchar,@district),'%')+''''
if(@block is not null)
  set @querystr += ' and convert(varchar,schoolmaster.block_id) LIKE '''+ISNULL(convert(varchar,@block),'%')+''''
if(@udisecode is not null)
  set @querystr += ' and a.udise_no LIKE '''+ISNULL(@udisecode,'%')+''''
if(@className is not null)
  set @querystr += ' and a.class_id LIKE '''+ISNULL(@className,'%')+''''
if(@category is not null)
  set @querystr += ' and CONVERT(varchar,b.student_category) LIKE '''+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar,@category),'%')+''''
if(@religion is not null)
  set @querystr += ' and CONVERT(varchar,b.religion_id) LIKE '''+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar,@religion),'%')+''''
if(@gender is not null)
  set @querystr += ' and a.gender LIKE '''+ISNULL(@gender,'%')+''''

set @querystr += ' order by districtmaster.district_name,blockmaster.block_name'
print(@querystr)
--exec(@querystr)
```

**Syntax Error:**

```
Where and a.udise_no LIKE '1141701604' order by districtmaster.district_name,blockmaster.block_name
```

Comment: What is the syntax error? Post the SQL that `print(@querystr)` returns...

Comment: There a better ways, IMHO, but a common hack it to hard-code `WHERE 1 = 1` and then append supplied values like `IF @udisecode IS NOT NULL @querystr += ' AND udisecode = @udisecode'`. Most importantly, declare @udisecode as `nvarchar(MAX)` and execute the dynamic sql using as a parameterized query with `sp_executesql`.

Comment: @DaleK sir I have edited question and posted my error syntax generated in `WHERE clause`

Comment: Please don't call me sir. And where is the syntax error? I don't have access to your tables I can't see it myself.

Comment: @DaleK In my posted question I have added my `Syntax Error` portion. In this part kindly check `WHERE clause`.

Comment: You need to actually pull out the the syntax error - not expect us to wade through your large query and find it - since you already know where it is.

Comment: Build the where clause as a separate string, and test the length each time you append to it. If its emtpy add `where `, if its not add `and `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People use `where 1 = 1` because they're inherently lazy when building dynamic SQL queries. If you start with a `where 1 = 1` then all your extra clauses just start with `AND` and you don't have to figure out.

**Query Should be**

```
DECLARE @vflag VARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
        @udisecode VARCHAR(20) = '1141701604',
        @district INT = NULL,
        @zone INT = 0, 
        @block INT = NULL,  
        @classid INT = NULL,
        @className VARCHAR(10) = NULL, 
        @report VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
        @gender VARCHAR(6) = NULL,
        @religion INT = NULL, 
        @category INT = NULL, 
        @subjectid INT = NULL, 
        @subject VARCHAR(30) = NULL,
        @querystr VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

SET @querystr = '
    ;with cte1 AS(
       SELECT udise_no,student_regno,fullname,dob,domicile_yesno,admission_date,gender,class_id from tbl_personal
    ),cte2 AS(
       SELECT udise_no,student_regno,religion_id,student_category,student_caste from tbl_reservation
    ),cte3 AS(
       SELECT categoryname,ID from tbl_category
    ),cte4 AS(
       SELECT id,religion from tbl_religion
    ),cte5 AS(
       SELECT udisecode,school_name,district_id,block_id from school_master
    ),cte6 AS(
       SELECT district_id,district_name from district_master
    ),cte7 AS(
       SELECT block_id,block_name,district_id from block_master
    )

    SELECT a.udise_no, a.fullname AS studentname,a.gender,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.dob,106),'' '',''-'') AS dob, ISNULL(d.categoryname,'''') AS category,
            ISNULL(c.religion,'''') AS religion, a.domicile_yesno AS domicile,a.class_id AS class, a.student_regno, schoolmaster.school_name, 
            districtmaster.district_name AS district, blockmaster.block_name
    FROM cte1 a LEFT JOIN cte2 b ON b.udise_no = a.udise_no AND b.student_regno = a.student_regno
    LEFT JOIN cte4 c ON c.ID = b.religion_id
    LEFT JOIN cte3 d ON d.ID = b.student_category
    LEFT JOIN cte5 schoolmaster ON a.udise_no = schoolmaster.udisecode
    LEFT JOIN cte6 districtmaster ON districtmaster.district_id = schoolmaster.district_id
    LEFT JOIN cte7 blockmaster ON blockmaster.district_id = districtmaster.district_id AND  blockmaster.district_id = schoolmaster.district_id AND blockmaster.block_id = schoolmaster.block_id' 


IF(@district IS NOT NULL OR @block IS NOT NULL OR @udisecode IS NOT NULL OR @className IS NOT NULL OR @category IS NOT NULL OR @religion IS NOT NULL OR @gender IS NOT NULL)
    SET @querystr +=  ' WHERE 1 = 1'
IF(@district IS NOT NULL)
    SET @querystr +=  'AND convert(VARCHAR,schoolmaster.district_id) LIKE '''+ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR,@district),'%')+''''
IF(@block IS NOT NULL)
    SET @querystr +=  ' AND convert(VARCHAR,schoolmaster.block_id) LIKE '''+ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR,@block),'%')+''''
IF(@udisecode IS NOT NULL)
    SET @querystr +=  ' AND a.udise_no LIKE '''+ISNULL(@udisecode,'%')+''''
IF(@className IS NOT NULL)
    SET @querystr +=  ' AND a.class_id LIKE '''+ISNULL(@className,'%')+''''
IF(@category IS NOT NULL)
    SET @querystr +=  ' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,b.student_category) LIKE '''+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@category),'%')+''''
IF(@religion IS NOT NULL)
    SET @querystr +=  ' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,b.religion_id) LIKE '''+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@religion),'%')+''''
IF(@gender IS NOT NULL)
    SET @querystr +=  ' AND a.gender LIKE '''+ISNULL(@gender,'%')+''''

SET @querystr +=  ' order by districtmaster.district_name,blockmaster.block_name'
PRINT(@querystr)
EXEC (@querystr)
```